# Field representation for the default value of lightning-record-form component in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to add some default values for some field for **lightning-record-form** in lightning web component in salesforce.

I have search through the web and found something like this.

```
<lightning-record-form
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    fields={fields}
    record-type-id={recordTypeId}
>
</lightning-record-form>
```

Where fields are represented in the controller like this,|

```
fields = [NAME_FIELD, ACCOUNT_FIELD];
```

or

```
fields = [
    { fieldApiName: 'Name', objectApiName: 'Custom_Object__c' },
    { fieldApiName: 'Account__c', objectApiName: 'Custom_Object__c'}
];
```

both works fine if I don't need any predefined value. I am trying to add predefined value using the fields representation syntax like,

```
fields = [
    { fieldApiName: 'Name', objectApiName: 'Custom_Object__c', value: 'Sample Name' },
    { fieldApiName: 'Account__c', objectApiName: 'Custom_Object__c', value: '0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXQAF'}
];
```

Default value is not setting.I don't know if I am using the proper way or not, or there could be another way. Please someone help me with this?

**Note:** I know that I can use **lightning-record-edit-form** and **lightning-input-field** to full fill my requirements. In this way I have to add every field using **lightning-input-field** which I don't want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation),

> **Prepopulating Field Values**
>
> **lightning-record-form** does not support prepopulating of field values
> when the form loads. To create a form that displays custom field
> values, use the **lightning-record-edit-form** component.

Comment: I know about **lightning-record-edit-form**, was looking solutions for **lightning-record-form**. Thanks for the reply.